# Iterated integral $\int _0^{\pi }\int _{-\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{\pi }{2}} (4\sin(x) + 7\cos(y)) \,dx\,dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$\int _0^{\pi }\int _{-\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{\pi }{2}} (4\sin(x) + 7\cos(y)) \,dx\,dy$

To evaluate this iterated integral, I start with the integral with respect to $x$ and then  $y$

$\int_0^{\pi} \left( \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (4\sin(x) + 7\cos(y)) \,dy \right) \,dx$

Now I calculate the integral with respect to $y$

$\int_0^{\pi} \left[ 4y\sin(x) + 7\sin(y) \right]_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \,dx$

I substitute the limits of integration:

$\int_0^{\pi} \left[ 4\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\sin(x) + 7\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) - \left(4\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\sin(x) + 7\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right) \right] \,dx$

We abbreviate the expressions:

$\int_0^{\pi} \left[ 4\pi\sin(x) + 14 \right] \,dx$

Now I calculate the integral with respect to $x$:

$\left[ -4\pi\cos(x) + 14x \right]_0^{\pi}$

I substitute the limits of integration:

$\left[ -4\pi\cos(\pi) + 14\pi \right] - \left[ -4\pi\cos(0) \right] = -4\pi(-1) + 14\pi +4\pi(1)-14(0)= 22\pi$

These were my calculations, but the website where I enter them says they are incorrect. Where is the error and how to correct it?

Comment: WolframAlpha (and Mathematica) [agrees](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+4sin%28x%29%2B7+cos%28y%29+from+y%3D-pi%2F2+to+pi%2F2%2Cx%3D0+to+pi) with your answer. So the error isn't with the calculation.

Comment: @Semiclassical Strange. Mine [disagrees](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5B4sinx%2B7cosy%2C%7Bx%2C-Divide%5Bpi%2C2%5D%2CDivide%5Bpi%2C2%5D%7D%2C%7By%2C0%2Cpi%7D%5D). I may be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question asks to integrate with respect to $\mathrm{d}x$ first, followed by $\mathrm{d}y$. You have swapped the order of integration, without swapping the limits appropriately - thus you have obtained an incorrect answer.

If we follow the order of integration given in the question, we obtain:

$$ I = \int_0^{\pi} ( 0 + 7 \cdot \pi \cdot \mathrm{cos}y) \mathrm{d}y = 7\pi \cdot 0 = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change the sequence of integral, so I think you made a mistake in the first time adding a small parentheses, here is my process.
$\begin{aligned}I&=\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(4sin(x)+7cos(y))dxdy\\&=\int_{0}^{\pi}[-4cos(x)+7xcos(y)]|_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}dy\\&=\int_{0}^{\pi}[7\pi cos(y)]\\&=7\pi sin(y)|_{0}^{\pi}\\&=0\end{aligned}$
I hope it will help.